# Note able to set count on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 dropdown with values `N/A`, `3`, `5`, `6`. On change event if I change value of first drop down the count should be `1` always but whenever I change again value is keep increasing. I know my counter is wrong but not getting idea to fix it.

```
$count = 0;
$maxcount = 3;
$arrOfLevel2ElementId.each(function () {
    arrOfLevel2ElementId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + arrOfLevel2ElementId).on('change', function () {
        level2ElementVal = $(this).val();
        if (level2ElementVal == "N/A") {
            if ($count > 0) {
                $count--;
            } else {
                $count;
            }
            showOutput($sum);
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($count <= $maxcount) {
                $count++;
            } else {
                $count;
            }
            alert($count);
            $sum = parseInt(level2ElementVal);
            showOutput($sum);
        }
```

Comment: Your description of the issue doesn't really make sense. Could you show us a working example of the problem, in a http://jsfiddle.net? At least seeing your HTML would help.

Comment: JsFiddle or it didn't happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the case because as soon as you change the dropdown, you call the function.

Here you state that `if(level2ElementVal == "N/A")` you decrease the count.

But in the else statement, meaning you select either `3`, `5` or `6`, you check if the count isn't at the maxcount. Which is not the case if `$count = 1`. Then you increase it. Which explains that it increases when you change the value.

I'm not sure why you have a `$maxcount`, but if you were to change it to 1, my assumption is that your count should not exceed 1.

EDIT:

If what I've understand correctly from your comments you want to device the three numbers, unless its on `N/A`.

Try this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7b21b699/1/

It sets the value field when the last field is changed and checks the values at that point. Then sums them up when needed and divides them correctly.

```
$("#box3").on('change', function(){
    var val1 = $("#box1").val();
    var val2 = $("#box2").val();
    var val3 = $("#box3").val();
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;

    if(val1 != "N/A"){
        sum += parseInt(val1);
        count++;
    }
    if(val2 != "N/A"){
        sum += parseInt(val2);
        count++;
    }
    if(val3 != "N/A"){
        sum += parseInt(val3);
        count++;
    }

    var result = sum / count;

    $("#value").text(result);

});


<select class="form-control" id="box1" name="a">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a value</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="box2" name="a">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a value</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="box3" name="a">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a value</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id ="value">value comes here</div>
```

Comment: Actually I have to sum up the selected value of the dropdown and have to divide by their count but if it is "N/A" than my count will not increase.

Comment: It's a bit hard to grasp what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could expand your question a bit.

Comment: You're calling to functions that aren't available in the fiddle, but from what I can see you are trying to divide the three chosen numbers, Unless one is on "N/A", then you want to divide it by two.